# @author and @version Tags in Enumeration's Doc Comment

Tags: java, javadoc

Do I have to put the `@author` and `@version` tags in the documentation comment of an enumeration?
[How to Write Doc Comments for the Javadoc Tool](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html) says

> `* @author`      (classes and interfaces only, required)
>
> `* @version`     (classes and interfaces only, required. See footnote 1)

and my IDE's documentation comment template for enumerations includes `@author`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put into Javadoc, whatever your organization mandates should be put in Javadoc. At the end of the day its a communication tool, you decide which parts of it you want to use and which you don't.

Answer (score 0):

An enum type is a kind of class (and an annotation type is a kind of interface).

Thus when it says *classes and interfaces only*, it actually means *types only*, and includes enum types (but excludes methods, fields, constructors and packages).